# Can I store LINQ query result in an array?

Tags: c#, linq

This is the code using LINQ, it stores the values into list

```
string StringRegex = "\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"";

        Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryofString = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"String", StringRegex}
        };

 var matches = dictionaryofString.SelectMany(a => Regex.Matches(input,a.Value)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(b =>
                new
                {
                    Index = b.Index,
                    Value = b.Value,
                    Token = a.Key
                }))
        .OrderBy(a => a.Index).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 < matches.Count)
            {
                int firstEndPos = (matches[i].Index + matches[i].Value.Length);
                if (firstEndPos > matches[(i + 1)].Index)
                {
                    matches.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match);
        }
```

Can it not be stored into Array? Where I can display only item I want. Just like here the output is {Index=, Value=, Token=}
Meanwhile I want the output that be of just "Value" "Token" index not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ToArray` instead. But `List` gives you the desired array functionality already, you can access an item by its index.

```
var exampleQuery = select c from componentsDemo;
var list = exampleQuery.ToList();
var secondElement = list[1]; // <- demo only, there could be an exception thrown, if there's less than two elements in the list
```

EDIT: as I can see from your comments, you need this:

```
foreach (var match in matches)
{
   Console.WriteLine(match.Value + ", " + match.Token); 
}
```

Comment: This is the first time I'm using ToList function. And can't control the output.
for instance, current output is {Index=0, Value="asd", Token=String"}
I want the output to be: "asd" Token

Comment: Marko, it worked but it only shows the value field, can it be concatenated with token field too?

Comment: Yes do match.Value + match.Token

Comment: @Marko Juvančič "Or this" option will not work for OP, Is suggested similar, needs Index also for further processing

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I didn't see that part of the code.